# lround on Visual Studio not being recognized

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am working on compiling a library that uses `lround` in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7.  The code is real simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double dfoo = 42.546;
    int ifoo = lround ( dfoo );

    std::cout << dfoo << " => " << ifoo << std::endl;

    return ( 0 );
}
```

I am able to do this on Linux using g++.  MSDN Forum says that it should compile.  Yet, Visual Studio gives me the error saying `lround` is not found.  Exact error is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: testnorm, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  testnorm.cpp
1>c:\users\sanjiv\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\testnorm\testnorm\testnorm.cpp(7): error C3861: 'lround': identifier not found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Can someone see what could be wrong?  Am I missing some compiler directive for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use C99 math functions, but Visual Studio is not a C99 compiler.

You can instead use the overloaded `std::round` from `#include <cmath>`.  Newer Visual C++ should also have `std::lround`.

Comment: Both `std::round` and `std::lround` are not recognized.  I thought that VS 2012 was fairly recent.  Anyway, for now, I have fixed the problem by writing my own function calling it `lround`.  I am still interested in knowing why this won't work though with the standard Math library.

Comment: @unxnut: Did you `#include <cmath>` as my answer states?

Comment: @unxnut: Oh, looks like `std::round` is also new in C++11.